# When the רא״ש refers to "הגאון", who is he referring to?

Tags: rabbis, historical-figures, rishonim, geonim, rabbeinu-asher

A friend posted on Facebook the following question, and I couldn't solve it based on any context, so I thought I'd bring it here.

**When the רא״ש refers to "הגאון", who is he referring to?**

Is there someone he generally calls by that title?

Comment: Where is this רא״ש? Sometimes (usually actually) the רא״ש begins by quoting the Rif. If this quote of the גאון is in the quote of the Rif, it's probably from either the בה״ג or ר׳ האי.

Answer (score 5):

From [the Sefer Mei Ber Mayim Chaim chapter 4: pg 85](https://books.google.com/books?id=GSAvAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA85&lpg=RA1-PA85&dq=%D7%94%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9F+%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%22%D7%A9) it seems that it is referring to Rav Hai Gaon.